# Where does oracle store metadata when queries are run from scripts?

Tags: oracle

Does oracle store the query run inside of scripts ?

If so, where ?

Also, can i find which query is from which script ?

I found v$sql but it doesnt have a link to pid. It has a "module" field that isnt useful for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide metadata for code executed in Oracle, whether from scripts, application servers, or PL/SQL code, the best way may be to use [DBMS_Application_Info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_appinf.htm).

This associates the executed code with meaningful module and action names, so you could use the module "SQL*Plus Script" for all of your scripts and actions such as "Export invoices".